# Script to upload files to Azure Storage File Share

Tags: file, azure, storage, share

Situation:
I just created an Azure Storage file share and I figured out how to upload files via script (C#) to the Azure BLOB storage.

Problem:
I want to upload files via script to my Azure storage file share (not BLOB). I already installed the Azure CLI but the problem is I have to login first (az login) before I can take any actions.

Is there any way to upload files from a folder based on my PC to the Azure storage file share (testuser.file.core.windows.net\test) without mounting it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do take a look at AzCopy tool. This is a command line tool available on both Windows and Linux using which you can upload files from your local computer to Azure File share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are multiple was to accomplish this.  If you only problem is the login part then you can use Service principal and certificate to automate login.

example

`az login --service-principal -u http://azure-cli-2016-08-05-14-31-15 -p ~/mycertfile.pem --tenant contoso.onmicrosoft.com`

You can see more options by using

`az login -h`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to upload files from a folder based on my PC to the Azure storage file share (testuser.file.core.windows.net\test) without mounting it?

Yes, we also could use the C# code to upload file to azure file storage. Please have a try to use the following code.

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("storage connection string");
// Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to File storage.
 CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

 // Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
 CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("test");

 share.CreateIfNotExists();

 CloudFile cloudFile = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("fileName");

 Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"localpath");

 cloudFile.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
```